# Ad image in full screen for mobile devices without scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I would like to create an HTML/CSS/Javascript page that can show a picture (an ads) in full screen for mobiles. Smartphones + tablets. The ads stretch to the maximum width and height and there is no scrollbar.

I try two diferent ways :

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
var screenHeight = $(window).height();

$('body, .ads-picture').css('width', screenWidth+'px');
$('body, .ads-picture').css('height', screenHeight+'px');
```

And in other way with media queries for each devices.

But it doesn't work in any situation. In iPhone 5 the picture is not in full screen (I need to scroll), in iPad mini also.

Can you help me please ? Thanks !!!

Comment: are you showing the add as a pop-up?

Comment: plz post your code here or fiddle..

Answer (score 0):

add the following tag and put width: 100% im the images

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

get more info about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)